# SSL connection fails with IOS5.1 on 3G connection

Tags: ios5, ssl, 3g, afnetworking

Having just finished developing my new iOS app, I have stumbled upon a strange issue.

My API endpoint runs on SSL (nginx/openssl) with a Comodo SSL certification. When I am on wi-fi,  I can connect to it from both my application via AFNetworking and Safari on the iPhone. The issue arises when I switch to 3G. I can not connect to the API URL from neither one of them. Connection to Gmail via https works properly, so I can not blame my GSM operator.

The API endpoint that I utilize in one of my other apps is also failing with the same setup and it was working properly with iOS4.2.

My only guess is:

- iOS5 switched to TLS1.2 and nginx/openssl combo does not support it. But in that case I wouldn't be able to connect when I am on wi-fi.

I am almost pulling my hair out for the last couple of hours, this is really frustrating. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: You haven't said what actually happens - do you get an NSError back, or it times out, or ... ?

Comment: It just times out when called from both Safari and via AFNetworking in my app.

Comment: Downgrading as it doesn't appear there was ever a real issue here related to IOS5.1

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys, I think I should get more sleep and less work. It was all related to a custom firewall rule that blocks port 443 for any IP not in my VPN. The only outcome of this problem is:

- Check your environment first!